# Timeout waiting for output from CGI script

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql

So my server error log is constantly full of this error:

Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /home/.../public_html/mydomain/index.php

Whatever this error is, I think it might be contributing to my website consistently getting overloaded and crashing/restarting.

Anyone have any insight as to what this is and a possible solution for it?

Comment: What kind of server do you have. mem, cpu etc, next to that, any heavy scripts you might be running or big customisations to Magento

Comment: I'm running a virtual server with the following specs:  4 cores, 4GB ram. I don't believe there's any heavy scripts, however I was told this morning by my web host that I've got a slew of slow mySQL queries that are bogging down the site. Here's an example of the files that they put into a txt file for me: http://trimfootco.com/list-slow-queries-04.05.2015.txt